# GST-RTSP-SERVER gst_rtsp_media_factory_set_transport_mode method on vala

Tags: gstreamer, vala

In C code we have next method `gst_rtsp_media_factory_set_transport_mode()`, 
but vala VAPI haven't implement of this functional. How can I do this?

Comment: Please provide your code and show, what you try to do to this time.

Comment: I try convert next code from C to VALA https://github.com/GStreamer/gst-rtsp-server/blob/master/examples/test-record.c But i can't find in vala method called factory_set_transport_mode()

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1):

The bindings to GStreamer make use of GObject Introspection and it looks like the [source GObject Introspection Repository for GstRtspServer](https://github.com/nemequ/vala-girs/blob/master/gir-1.0/GstRtspServer-1.0.gir) is a bit out of date. An [issue has been raised](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/vala/issues/653) in the Vala repository to get this fixed. Many Vala GIR bindings are regularly updated to track upstream projects, especially projects like GTK+ and GStreamer, but this one seems to have been missed.

The binding is in the process of being updated in the Vala release, but if you want to get on then you can download the new binding from Vala's staging branch. Download [gstreamer-rtsp-server-1.0.vapi](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/vala/blob/3784fdc6d0cac872f43d443c403132b2e4f3b7ac/vapi/gstreamer-rtsp-server-1.0.vapi)  and [gstreamer-rtsp-server-1.0.deps](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/vala/blob/3784fdc6d0cac872f43d443c403132b2e4f3b7ac/vapi/gstreamer-rtsp-server-1.0.deps) and save it in a directory called `vapi` in your project. You need to add that to your VAPI search path. From your project directory this would be something like:

```
valac --vapidir vapi --pkg gstreamer-rtsp-server-1.0 rtsp_server_example.vala
```

This will override the binding you are currently using. The updated binding will, however, be available from your distribution with Vala 0.40.8.

Comment: This information completely solved my problems. Thank you very much.